# how can we create posts and pages using wordpress REST APIs?

Tags: wordpress, web

I have a preformatted HTML string that I want to use to create a POST or PAGE through wordpress REST APIs. The purpose is to avoid formatting after the POST or PAGE is created.

The problem is wordpress apis to create post/page do not take HTML as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can pass your content as a json format. Please check the screenshot

[image]